# 408 Request Timeout on multipart/form-data upload

Tags: python, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipart

I am experiencing a 408 Request Timeout error when trying to replicate a POST through python.

When using Chrome Dev-tools I can see that the payload of the request looks like the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryrDYOkUiAtKl4GqZG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_pic"; filename="maxresdefault.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryrDYOkUiAtKl4GqZG--
```

Using the requests modules `files` argument I replicate the post and it comes out like this:

```
--e63ccee0b5784603a6c12c213929fe09
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_pic"; filename="maxresdefault.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

���� JFIF  ` `  �� "Exif  MM *               �� C        



�� C�� ��" ��               
�� �   } !1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 

--e63ccee0b5784603a6c12c213929fe09--
```

The headers on my replicated post match those of the official post that shows up in chrome dev-tools.
When I delete the payload or rather the `files = files` argument from the session.post I get a 200 OK response back saying it was successful.

However, as you can guess, there is no image because I am not sending one.

Seeing that I get a 200 OK response when removing the payload, and a 408 Request Timeout when adding it, it makes me almost sure I am screwing up the actual upload.

I've tried things like downsizing the image but it's giving me the same error.

The 408 Request Timeout is instant as well, there is no hint of it actually "timing out" after waiting for a bit, it's instant when the session.post is made.

See here how I perform the post:

`r = session.post(URL, headers=headers, files=files)
        print r.status_code, r.text`

See here how the `files` variable is made:

`profile_picture_path = self.user_details('avatar')
        profile_picture_name = ntpath.basename(profile_picture_path)
        files = {'profile_pic': (profile_picture_name, open(profile_picture_path), 'image/jpeg')}`

Comment: What is the web server that returns this error?

Comment: I cannot disclose that information due to a confidentiality agreement